# I want to add a JS tag into the header and before the </body> tag of every page of a site with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to add a couple of tags into the page in every page of a site with greaemonkey....

just before the `</head>` I want to add for example

`<script src="//bllaaablaaa.js"></script>`

and before the `</body>`

`<script src="//bllaaablaaa2.js"></script>`

Can anyone help with a userscript to do this? OR how I would do it in greaesmonkey????

Comment: document.head.appendchild(your script tag ) ;

Comment: so.....
 
document.head.appendchild(<script src="//bllaaablaaa.js"></script>)  
 
document.body.appendchild(<script src="//bllaaablaaa2.js"></script>)

Comment: This doesnt work.....
// ==/UserScript==
document.head.appendchild("<script src="//assets.adobedtm.com/2016687db8840fa748bbdc966b49915a93243a15/satelliteLib-9704459793322e5da14fdd9e45d2c4bcb3e9d341.js"></script>");
document.body.appendchild("<script type="text/javascript">_satellite.pageBottom();</script>")

Comment: var fileref = document.createElement('script')
                    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
                    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename) and then document.head.appendchild(fileref) ;